# How to use 1 file with variables for less and sass

Tags: css, sass, kendo-ui, less, semantic-ui

Is there a way to use just one file with variables and use it within a sass *and* a less CSS-framework?

In my react project I use semantic UI (less) and kendo react (sass). For comfortability reasons, I want to write only one file including variables like colors, paddings, gaps ...

in kendo theming is pretty easy.
I've found a way to use variables / theming within semantic too. 
[Here is the link](https://jsramblings.com/2018/03/04/how-to-use-semantic-ui-with-a-custom-theme-in-your-CRA-app.html)

but now I can't get both frameworks working with just a single var file together as one is using sass and one less.

could find any solution online too.

// semantic site.variables
@fontName: 'Lato';

//kendo variables.scss
$niceBgColor: pink;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@width: 10px;//less
$theme1-PEOGCS:#615149;//SASS dark grey
```

- They have different way of declaring variables and you should
  completely separate LESS From SASS, for best practice.
- It is bad practice to use both on the same project unless you really
  have to do so.
- SASS and LESS have a slightly different syntax, you would end up
  having to maintain each separately.

**Good practice would be for example:**

- Add Main Folder to project name it: SASS

  File: main.scss
- inside of SASS create Helper Folder name it: Helper
- inside of it add these Files:

  _mixins.scss,_variables.scss,_placeholder.scss
  **To make the code easy to maintain and reuse. Same with less(similar)**

If there is a way to do what you want I don't recommend doing it, that's IF. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

How many variables do you have?

The potential problems with this will be much bigger than manually maintaining two files with a dozen of variables in each.

Kendo has older, less-based themes, although of inferior quality. Semantic UI has a [sass port](https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass). Even converting Semantic UI's less files yourself will be better than mixing less and sass.